# Does re-cloning a repo create a different .git structure?

Tags: git

I am trying to understand if *in general* cloning a repo is a deterministic operation regarding the files in the `.git` index.

I have re-cloned a repo, keeping the original clone as a backup. The backup and the newly cloned repo are identical, except for the stuff in `.git`. That is:

```
diff -r repo repo.bck
```

Shows a lot of differences, whereas:

```
diff -x .git -r repo repo.bck
```

Does not show any.

Is this expected?

Note: the repo in question is actually an encrypted repo, using filters during checkout/commit, so the difference in the index could be due to the way encryption is setup. But I actually think this is not the case, since the filters are used to checkout/commit files to/from the working dir, but should not affect the `.git` index.

Comment: If the original repository was cloned using old (e.g. v1.5) version of Git, it may have a bit different layout than re-cloned one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation.

1. If you clone a repository from a remote repository, the git objects in the remote repository should be packed before transporting via network, and they are stored in your `.git/objects` without unpacking after transporting. So it is natural that there is big difference between the two repositories.
2. Even if you clone a repository from a local disk, the new repository may have difference from original repository because `.git/config` should have `remote` section to tell you where this repository cloned from. But basically there is no differences for files in  `.git/objects` because they are hard-linked from original repository's.

If you tell me more about your situation and about the difference, I will update this answer.